Create in-app products and subscriptions with similar IDs. Google Play
I have right now two versions to pay for in my app:

PLUS (in-app product)
PRO (subscription)

I'd like to have an in-app product and a subscription for each version. Specially to make it simpler for the user.
Is this possible from Google Play Console without creating 2 in-app products and 2 subscriptions and applying extra logic in my app to show them together as a group?
Can I apply offers to subscriptions if the bought an in-app product before? (I only see discounts among subscriptions)
